# Powershell Get-Help from Comment Based gives too many blank lines

Tags: powershell, function

I know I might be picky, but I can't understand the "pattern" of the Get-Help and why there is one, 2 or even 3 blank lines!

Here is the actual part of the code I use :

```
Function New-ChromeDriver {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Start the ChromeDriver and launch a new Chrome Browser for powershell automation.
.DESCRIPTION
    This function create a new Chrome with the ChromeDriver with all the required options. You can use the flags to start it incognito and/or headless.
    Really usefull for powershell automation.

    Will create and populate global variables : $Driver, $Wait, $mainHandle and $ExpectedConditions
.INPUTS
    -Incognito [Optional flag]
    -Headless [Optional flag]
.OUTPUTS
    None
.LINK
    Confluence to be added
.LINK
    GitLab to be added
#>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Void])]
    Param (
    # If present, activate the incognito browsing mode
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][switch]$incognito,
    # If present, Chrome will start headless (not shown at all in windows)
    [parameter(mandatory=$false)][switch]$headless
    )

    Try {
...
    } Catch {
...
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

```
PS C:\> Get-Help New-ChromeDriver -full

NAME
    New-ChromeDriver
    
SYNOPSIS
    Start the ChromeDriver and launch a new Chrome Browser for powershell automation.
    
    
SYNTAX
    New-ChromeDriver [-incognito] [-headless] [<CommonParameters>]
    
    
DESCRIPTION
    This function create a new Chrome with the ChromeDriver with all the required options. You can use the flags to start it incognito and/or headless.
    Really usefull for powershell automation.
    
    Will create and populate global variables : $Driver, $Wait, $mainHandle and $ExpectedConditions
    

PARAMETERS
    -incognito [<SwitchParameter>]
        If present, activate the incognito browsing mode
        
        Required?                    false
        Position?                    named
        Default value                False
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?  false
        
    -headless [<SwitchParameter>]
        If present, Chrome will start headless (not shown at all in windows)
        
        Required?                    false
        Position?                    named
        Default value                False
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?  false
        
    <CommonParameters>
        This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
        ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
        OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see 
        about_CommonParameters (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216). 
    
INPUTS
    -Incognito [Optional flag]
    -Headless [Optional flag]
    
    
OUTPUTS
    None
    
    
    
RELATED LINKS
    Confluence to be added 
    GitLab to be added
```

Do someone know if I'm doing something wrong?
And how we can get something prettier?

I did try to add lines, remove tabs, but always getting this weird spacing.

Comment: I think the issue is the Text Editor you are using and options.  The return may be using the wrong type.  Returns can be 0x0d, 0x0a  or just 0x0a.  You are probably adding 0x0d, 0x0a and getting two lines instead of one.

Comment: How would you like the output to be? Do note the output from `Get-Help` are all objects so can design your own preferred output. Try `Get-Help New-ChromeDriver -full | Select-Object *`

Comment: @zett42 you might be looking at `help` and not `Get-Help` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon OMFG, I was looking at my [customized `Get-Help` proxy function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72549014/7571258) which actually outputs a string. 

Comment: Good question with no answer.  Just look at extra lines after the OUTPUTs section.  Why is it so different from the number of blank lines after INPUTS section?